# QtDesigner - adding splitter layouts to larger layouts

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I'm new to Qt Designer, and I am working on a main window where I want to have two list widgets off to the right, laid out in a vertical splitter, and then a larger text browser widget to the left, which is then itself in a splitter with the list widgets.  So the relative sizes of the list widgets can be resized vertically, and the horizontal space between the text browser and the other two widgets can also be resized.

I tried first laying out the two widgets on the right in a vertical splitter, and then selecting the layout, like so:

[image]

The problem is, now that the two list widgets are in the splitter layout, I can't then add that layout to any other larger layouts.  All the options appear grayed out.  If I just do a standard horizontal or vertical layout, it is possible to then make larger layouts out of smaller ones.  So how is this to be done when using splitter layouts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look's like you are selecting two `ListWidgets` instead `splitter`. To combine layouts you need to select one `splitter` which contains `ListWidgets` and then `TextBrowser`. In this case `Lay Out Horizontaly in splitter` will be available.

Here [video demonstration (1.25 MB)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3043766/qt_splitter.avi)